# row click event not fired after pagination in bootstrap datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using bootstrap datatable for  pagination.I also added click event to each row.But the click event fired only in the first page. It does not work after sorting or pagination.Here is my  php code to display data

```
        <table id='tblCustomers' class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                                 <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                              <th>Customer id</th>
                                               <th>Company</th>
                                              <th>First name</th>
                                              <th>Last name</th>
                                              <th>Email</th>
                                              <th>Last login</th>
                                              <th>No Of logins </th>
                                   </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                 <tbody>";
                                foreach ($this->result as $row) {
                                    echo "<tr>
                                            <td>{$row['customerid']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['company']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['firstname']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['lastname']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['email']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['lastlogin']} </td>
                                            <td>{$row['count']}</td>
                                          </tr>";

                                     }
                                  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

and the jquery code is

```
                        $(function () {
                         $("#tblCustomers").dataTable();
                         $("#tblCustomers tr").click(function(){
                         alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
                         });
                       });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change code to below . this is call [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
    $(function () {
           $("#tblCustomers").dataTable();
           $(document).on('click',"#tblCustomers tr",function(){
                     alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
           });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#tblCustomers tr").on('click', function(){...}` instead of the regular `click`..

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, even the search and filter won't take the row click event. if you are providing the events on row like click,double-click.

On filter and On search make sure you call that function which has all your custom scripts.